# Remove BOTH items from list, if one value appears multiple times (Python)

Tags: python, list, duplicates

[Python: How to remove all duplicate items from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764909/python-how-to-remove-all-duplicate-items-from-a-list)

Hey guys

I have a list of (file,inode,image,hash)-tuples. I need to delete BOTH items if they have the same hash. I don't have that much of programming experience, so maybe a hint for what i have to look would already be helpful.
I've already searched the Internet, but the only thing i found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764909/python-how-to-remove-all-duplicate-items-from-a-list).
So far I've come up with this (extremely awkward) solution:

```
        hashlist = {}
        files_tobe_removed = []
        for (file, inode, image, hash) in self.files_for_json:
            hashlist[hash] = 0
        for (file, inode, image, hash) in self.files_for_json:
            hashlist[hash] +=1
        for (k,v) in hashlist.iteritems():
            if v == 2:
                files_tobe_removed.append(k)
        for (file,inode,image,hash) in self.files_for_json:
            if hash in files_tobe_removed:
                path = self.outDir + file
                os.remove(path)
                self.files_for_json.remove((file,inode,image,hash))
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should check if `v>1` in case there are three or more identical hashes. Beware of hash collisions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> L=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3]
>>> [k for k,v in Counter(L).items() if v==1]
[7, 8, 9]
```

To clarify:

```
hash_counter = Counter(x[3] for x in self.files_for_json)
for (file,inode,image,hash) in self.files_for_json:
    if hash_counter[hash]>1:
        # duplicated hash
        ...
```

Comment: For a list of tuples it won't look so elegant. :-)

Comment: @DrTyrsa, why would you use a list of tuples? Surely you'd just use a list of the hashes.

Comment: So you need one iteration to construct a list of tuples. Second iteration to count them with Counter. And third iteration to remove the elements. While it can be solved in two iterations.

Comment: @DrTyrsa, I first used 3 iterations to make it fit the OP code better. Now I changed it to use just 2 iterations