# Remove duplicate items from list

Tags: python, list, set

I tried following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764909/python-how-to-remove-all-duplicate-items-from-a-list) but, it doesnt seem to be working for me.

I tried this code:

```
for bresult in response.css(LIST_SELECTOR):
    NAME_SELECTOR = 'h2 a ::attr(href)'
    yield {
        'name': bresult.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
    }
                                                                                  b_result_list.append(bresult.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first())

    #set b_result_list to SET to remove dups, then change back to LIST
    set(b_result_list)
    list(set(b_result_list))
for brl in b_result_list:
    print("brl: {}".format(brl))
```

**This prints out:**

```
brl: https://facebook.site.com/users/login
brl: https://facebook.site.com/users
brl: https://facebook.site.com/users/login
```

When I just need:

```
brl: https://facebook.site.com/users/login
brl: https://facebook.site.com/users
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are discarding the result when you need to save it ... `b_result_list` never actually changes... so you are just iterating over the original list. instead save the result of the `set` operation

```
b_result_list = list(set(b_result_list))
```

(note that `set`s do not preserve order)

Comment: Wow, silly me. I must be getting tired. Thanks @Joran ! Ill accept as soon as I can

Comment: Here, it is not necessary to type-case the `set` back to `list`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri that may be true ... but i didnt want to make assumtions

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain order and uniqueify, you can do:

```
>>> li
['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '1', '1', '4', '5', '4', '6', '6']
>>> seen=set()
>>> [e for e in li if not (e in seen or seen.add(e))]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

Or, you can use the keys of an OrderedDict:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict([(k, None) for k in li]).keys()
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

But a set alone may substantially change the order of the original list:

```
>>> list(set(li))
['1', '3', '2', '5', '4', '6']
```