# Manipulate list in dataframe (duplicate and remove)

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a column containing lists with multiple elements:
such as [Japan, Japan, nan, nan, USA, USA,]

I want to remove duplicates and 'nan' value obtaining a list as below:

[Japan, USA]

The list is made from another dataframe with combining elements in different columns.

Comment: check the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764909/python-how-to-remove-all-duplicate-items-from-a-list

Comment: @kogito Thanks. It is helpful.